# Copy & Paste is not working in Code::Blocks

Tags: code-blocks

When I am pasting, all I see is `^V`. 
I even try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>,
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>, etc. 
Why is it not working?

Comment: The statement that (Ctrl)+(V) “pastes” `^V` seems to be inaccurate and misleading.   (Ctrl)+(A) doesn’t *paste* `^A`, it simply *is **displayed as* `^A`**.   If you get `^V` when you press (Ctrl)+(V), that simply means that you’re talking to a program that doesn’t interpret (Ctrl)+(V) as a keyboard shortcut.   Sure, the clipboard *might* be empty, but that’s irrelevant.

Comment: I tried on notepad it pasted there. But not on code blocks terminal. I used Code:Blocks for 2 years. Recently is not working otherwise it's working.